# How to use createFromString() in Craft 3

Tags: craft3, datetime

In Craft 2 I've used [createFromString()](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v2/craft-datetime.html#method-createfromstring) as following:

```
DateTime::createFromString($pubDate, craft()->timezone)
```

But if I use this function in craft cms 3 then I'm getting the following error:

```
Call to undefined method DateTime::createFromString()
```

Is there any alternative way to use the createFromString() in Craft 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`toDateTime()` method](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-helpers-datetimehelper.html#method-todatetime) in the `DateTimeHelper` class:

```
DateTimeHelper::toDateTime($pubDate, true);
```